# Profile a method in the jar file using spring aop is not happening

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

My requirement is to profile the elastic search java api get method to find the execution timings.I have written a Spring AOP aspect to do this

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PerformanceAspect {

  private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(PerformanceAspect.class);

  @Pointcut("execution(*  org.elasticsearch.action..ActionRequestBuilder.get(..))")
  public void getESMethod() {}


  @Around("getESMethod()")
  public void profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOGGER.info("Calling the get method..");
    try {
        pjp.proceed();
        LOGGER.info("Method execution completed");
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        LOGGER.info("Method execution time "+elapsedTime);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

`ActionRequestBuilder` is in `elasticsearch.jar` which is loaded by maven. I am using the spring boot with maven. But looks like this aspect is not getting executed at all. Is it because this `ActionRequestBuilder` is in another JAR file ? If I change the pointcut to any other methods in the project it's working fine. How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: [This is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26034950/4604579) you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP only works on Spring Beans, i.e. classes instantiated and maintained by Spring. This seems to be a non-spring core ElasticSearch class. You need to move at least one level up and find out what Spring glue code calls this class, rewriting the pointcut to point at the Spring glue code.

But I'm not even sure that will work, as Spring Data uses its own proxy magic, so I'm not sure you can apply AOP proxies to those. The safest bet would be to point the pointcut at your code that calls ElasticSearch